# DateTime.ParseExact() raising exception

Tags: c#, datetime

`DateTime.ParseExact()` raising and the error message is

**The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.**

this way i tried to parse the date

```
 string strDate ="03/17/2014"
 DateTime dt= DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

so the above date is correct date then why i am getting error. what would be the best way to parse date when application run in any country and system pc date time setting can be anything. please guide me.

the moment i change the `datetime parseexact to only parse` like

```
 string strDate ="03/17/2014"
 DateTime dt= DateTime.Parse(strDate)
```

the above code works fine. so just tell me what was the problem in `ParseExact()` 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no 17 months, use `"MM/dd/yyyy"` instead of `"dd/MM/yyyy"`:

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.ParseExact("03/17/2014", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

**Update**:

> is it mandatory that we need to specify the format. i do not want to
>   specify the format then how to use it. basically the pc where
>   application will run there datetime setting can be anything like
>   dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy etc

You have a problem if it can be anything. What month is `02/03/2012`, february or march?  You have to specify a `string[]` of allowed formats. You can give it a priority by the order in the array. Then you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` with overload that takes a `string[]`.

Another approach would be to accept that you don't know the current culture but you know the string is a valid format of the current culture with  `/` as date-separator. Then you could clone the current `DateTimeFormat` and change the `DateSeparator`

Then you can even use `DateTime.Parse`:

```
var customDateTimeFormat = (DateTimeFormatInfo)DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
customDateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("17/03/2014", customDateTimeFormat);
```

This works for me in germany even if we use `.` as date-separator, i needed to use `"17/03/2014"` because the day comes before the month here.

Comment: is it mandatory that we need to specify the format. i do not want to specify the format then how to use it. basically the pc where application will run there datetime setting can be anything like dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy etc.

Comment: @Thomas: you have a problem if it can be anything. What month is `02/03/2012`, february or march?  You have to specify a `string[]` of allowed formats. You can give it a priority by the order in the array. Then you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` with overload that takes a `string[]`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Thomas: i have edited my answer to provide another approach.

Answer (score 6):

You have `month` before `day` in the value `"03/17/2014"` i.e `"MM/dd/yyyy"`, You get the exception because month should not be have 17 it could have values from 1 to 12. You can learn more about custom date formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: +1 would be even better if you use `M/d/yyyy`, since that will parse both single/double digit day / month.

Comment: @SonerGönül, it does :)

Comment: But the day suggest he might have month like 01

Comment: @Habib: You'd need to define "better" - looser parsing isn't always better. If you're expecting valid content to *always* have two digits, then it makes sense to throw an exception if that expectation is violated.

Comment: Yes Jon, you are absolutely right. It depends on the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

From [`The "MM" Custom Format` Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier)

> The "MM" custom format specifier represents the month as a number from
>   **01 through 12 (or from 1 through 13 for calendars that have 13
>   months)**.

You should probably change your day specifier with your month specifier like `MM/dd/yyyy`